# Not able to do a Git Commit after a Pull?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, tfs

I'm new with Git and I'm using it in conjunction with Visual Studio Online. I pulled up a site locally that I haven't worked on in a while and made some changes to it. I was able to do a local commit but then when I tried to do a Sync to push it to VSO I got a message that I couldn't because there were uncommitted changes. So, I did a Pull which brought up 15 new commits. That in and of itself is unusual because there shouldn't have been any changes in the remote repository that I didn't have locally. So I then tried Sync again but it gave and error that 1 uncommitted change would be overwritten with the merge.

I'm not really sure what to do from here. I don't know how to get the remote repository in sync with my local repository.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have some changes in your local copy you haven't ADDED yet

What happens when you run `git status`? If you want those changes to goto the remote you can then use `git add <relative file path>` or `git add --a` to add everything. Then you should be able to commit and push up.

If you don't want to sync those change you can use `git reset --hard` which will bring your local back to the latest commit.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to look at how to run the Git commands manually. I've only done it through the Visual Studio GUI so far.